# stats linregress slope and intercept wrong

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, seaborn

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

xx = np.load('./x.npy')
yy = np.load('./y.npy')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 8)
labels = ['C1', 'C2']
colors = ['r', 'b']

for idx in range(2):

    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': xx, 'y': yy[idx]})
   
    ax.set(xlim=(np.min(df.x), np.max(df.x)),
           ylim=(np.min(df.y), np.max(df.y)))

    p = sns.regplot('x',
                    'y',
                    df,
                    scatter=False,
                    order=2,
                    ax=ax,
                    label=labels[idx],
                    color=colors[idx])

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(
        x=p.get_lines()[0].get_xdata(),
        y=p.get_lines()[0].get_ydata())
       
    formula = str(slope)     + ' x\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO} '     + str(intercept)

    print('formula: ', formula)
```

I am trying to calculate the slope and intercept of the sns.regplot fit line and it gives me:

```
formula:  82.53958162912909 x² 130.19916935648575
formula:  82.53958162912909 x² 130.19916935648575
```

which:

1. Is wrong as you can see for the plot, for x value 6 , we expect y value around 600.
2. Slope and intercept is the same for the two lines. We would expect a small difference.

[image: plot]

You can find the x, y files [here](https://files.fm/u/kvs5u7ar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting the data from the `Line2D` object, even though you already have the data in `xx` and `yy`, but anyway:

When you calculate the regression in the loop, you are passing the same set of data (line `[0]`) at each iteration. I guess you mean to write

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(
            x=xx,
            y=yy[idx])
```

Comment: Hi, you are right about the line [0]. But even with xx and yy[idx] the slope and intercept does not comply with the y values.

Comment: I don't see how. for x=6, 82.5*x+130.2 = 625.2, which appears to match your data

Comment: It's not, `linregress` calculates a linear fit (first order)